# overwriting specific variables in simulink

Tags: matlab, constants, simulink, overwrite

here's a picture of my current simulink model:

[image]

the variable `initRun` is initialized to 1. so in the first simulation step the `else-case` will be activated and an image is stored to the variable `origImg`. And now additionally I want to set the variable `initRun`to 0, so that at the next simulation step the if-case will be activated. But I dont know how to do propperly.

My 2nd questions is concerning the initialization of the variable `origImg` at the block `Data Store Memory`. The variable must be initialized to a 176x144 matrix. I tried several ways but all failed.

I hope, you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For your `InitRun`, it might be simpler to use a [Clock](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/clock.html) block and a [Compare to Zero](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/comparetozero.html) block so that when `t > 0`, you can activate one condition, and another condition otherwise (which would be `t = 0`).

For initialisation of the Data Store Memory block, simply specify `zeros(176,144)` as the initial value in the block parameters (Signal Attributes tab). See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/datastorememory.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. your hint for the `Data Store Memory` initialization of `imgOrig` is doing the job.

But I dont think your suggestion for `initRun` will work, because later I will receive the velocity of a car via CANbus and depending on the velocity I choose one of the image processing-algorithms. therefore, if the velocity exceeds a certain border (currently `0.3km/h`), I also need to set the variable `initRun` to 1 again. The variable ìnitRun` tells me whether it is the first run of the image processing, when the velocity is `< 0.3 km/h`

Comment: Then you can combine the `t>0` condition with `v<0.3` using a Logical operator block (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/logicaloperator.html).